# Using cross_val_predict against test data set

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science

I'm confused about using cross_val_predict in a test data set.

I created a simple Random Forest model and used cross_val_predict to make predictions:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.cross_validation import cross_val_predict, KFold

lr = RandomForestClassifier(random_state=1, class_weight="balanced", n_estimators=25, max_depth=6)
kf = KFold(train_df.shape[0], random_state=1)
predictions = cross_val_predict(lr,train_df[features_columns], train_df["target"], cv=kf)
predictions = pd.Series(predictions)
```

I'm confused on the next step here. How do I use what is learnt above to make predictions on the test data set?

Comment: You have to `fit` your model first, then you can call `predict` on it.

Comment: The chosen answer is irrelevant to the question, and partly wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @DmitryPolonskiy commented, the model has to be trained (with the `fit` method) before it can be used to `predict`.

```
# Train the model (a.k.a. `fit` training data to it).
lr.fit(train_df[features_columns], train_df["target"])
# Use the model to make predictions based on testing data.
y_pred = lr.predict(test_df[feature_columns])
# Compare the predicted y values to actual y values.
accuracy = (y_pred == test_df["target"]).mean()
```

`cross_val_predict` is a method of cross validation, which lets you determine the accuracy of your model. Take a look at [sklearn's cross-validation page](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html).

Comment: Unfortunately this answer is wrong; it doesn't mention 'cross_val_predict' anywhere and, as others have answered, I don't think that you have to train before using the function - one of its features is precisely that it does the training, iteratively on the folds.

Comment: I think you're right @Helen. You should write your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think `cross_val_score` or `cross_val_predict` uses fit before predicting. It does it on the fly. If you look at the [documentation (section 3.1.1.1)](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html#obtaining-predictions-by-cross-validation), you'll see that they never mention fit anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure the question was answered. I had a similar thought. I want compare the results (Accuracy for example) with the method that does not apply CV. The CV valiadte accuracy is on the X_train and y_train. The other method fit the model using X_trian and y_train, tested on the X_test and y_test. So the comparison is not fair since they are on different datasets.

What you can do is using the estimator returned by the cross_validate

lr_fit = cross_validate(lr, train_df[features_columns], train_df["target"], cv=kf, return_estimator=Ture)

y_pred = lr_fit.predict(test_df[feature_columns])

accuracy = (y_pred == test_df["target"]).mean()

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).