# How to predict labels using cross-validation (Kfold) with sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I would like to compare the predictions of the same classifier.
As an **example**, I picked the Linear Discriminant Analysis classifier.

Therefore, I took a look in the documentation of sklearn.
I found these two websites:
[Link 1](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.KFold.html)
[Link 2](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_predict.html)

I would like to link them together: prediction of labels with the help of cross-validation (for **example** Kfold).

However, I cannot manage to make my code work.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_predict, KFold
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.discriminant_analysis import LinearDiscriminantAnalysis

X = np.array([[1, 2], [2, 4], [3, 2], [4, 4], [5, 2], [6, 4], [7, 2], [8, 4]])
Y = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])

Xtrain,Xtest,Ytrain,Ytest = train_test_split(X,Y,train_size=0.5,random_state=1)

clf = LinearDiscriminantAnalysis()
clf.fit(Xtrain, Ytrain)
LinearDiscriminantAnalysis(n_components=None, priors=None, shrinkage='auto', solver='lsqr', store_covariance=False, tol=0.001)

# without cross-valdidation
prediction = clf.predict(Xtest)

# with cross-valdidation
cv = KFold(n_splits=2)
prediction_cv = cross_val_predict(clf, X, Y, cv=cv)
```

Hopefully, someone can help me.

**EDIT:**

I think I need to explain more.
At the moment, I have 232 datapoints (X). Each point consists of 16 values and is assigned to a specific class.
I hope that I can improve the predictions (=less classification mistakes for unseen data points), when I am using cross-validation, like *Kfold* or *Leave One Out*.

With the line `cross_val_predict(clf, X, Y, cv=cv)`, Python does a Kfold cross-validation.

Now, let's say, I get new datapoints (`X_new`). How can I classify them?

Comment: Well, you are correct until now and have `prediction` and `prediction_cv`. How would you want to compare them? What you want to do, please describe in detail.

Comment: The code do not work until now. Neither I get a result for `prediction` nor for `prediction_cv`. Python do not like something in my code and I cannot figure out what.

Background: As soon as Python can calculate predictions, I would like to count the mistakes between the `predictions` and `Ytest` (the true labels / classes).

Comment: For the example data you have provided, please see the answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I presume you are getting a Traceback when you run your code that looks similar to this:

```
    376         # avoid division by zero in normalization
    377         std[std == 0] = 1.
--> 378         fac = 1. / (n_samples - n_classes)
    379 
    380         # 2) Within variance scaling

ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero
```

That's what I get when I run your code. The reason this happens is because you have 1 data point for each class, and so `n_samples - n_classes` will equal zero.

You can alleviate this by populating more examples or reducing the number of classes:

```
import numpy as np

from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_predict, KFold
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.discriminant_analysis import LinearDiscriminantAnalysis

X = np.array([[1, 2], [2, 4], [3, 2], [4, 4], [5, 2], [6, 4], [7, 2], [8, 4], [1, 2], [2, 4], [3, 2], [4, 4], [5, 2], [6, 4], [7, 2], [8, 4]])
Y = np.array([1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8])

Xtrain,Xtest,Ytrain,Ytest = train_test_split(X,Y,train_size=0.5,random_state=1)

clf = LinearDiscriminantAnalysis()
clf.fit(X, Y)

# without cross-valdidation
prediction = clf.predict(Xtest)

# with cross-valdidation
cv = KFold(n_splits=2)
prediction_cv = cross_val_predict(clf, X, Y, cv=cv)
```

If you have another problem, update your question.

**EDIT**:

For your updated question, it is a duplicate of this question: [Using cross_val_predict against test data set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41560177/using-cross-val-predict-against-test-data-set)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I understand now the `ZeroDivisionError`.

Is the codeline `LinearDiscriminantAnalysis(n_components=None, priors=None, shrinkage='auto', solver='lsqr', store_covariance=False, tol=0.001)` not relevant?

Comment: It looks like you copy pasted that from an example code snippet. That line is just the `__repr__` printed representation of your class. As it stands, that line isn't doing anything useful for you. If this answer solved your problem, it'd be great if you could accept it as an answer.